# Proliant DL360 Raid5 Hot Swap Drive

Tags: hp-proliant, raid5, hp-smart-array, hotswap

I have a DL360 G5 running WinSrvr2003 with a 3 drive (72GB) SAS Raid 5 array on P400i controller. The single array has two partitions. (OS and a data store)  Drive 2 has failed and is off line (Amber lite and internittant beeps)  I have replacement drives but cannot find step by step instruction on a hot swap and drive rebuild. Do I just pull the drive and insert the new drive while the system is online and running?

Im am familair with this procedure on Dell Poweredges but not so on the HP Proliant. Does anyone have links to this instruction?

Answer (score 9):

Yes, in this case, you would pull the bad drive and insert the new drive. 
HP Smart Array controllers initiate the rebuild process automatically.

This can be done hot, while the system is running.

A description of the HP Smart Array RAID controller technology is [available here](http://h20000.www2.hp.com/bc/docs/support/SupportManual/c00687518/c00687518.pdf).

Answer (score 0):

As far as resource links go, you can use HP's [web-based guided troubleshooter](http://www.hp.com/support/gts) to find out what to do for a failed drive with a solid amber LED.  You can also find this information in the ["ProLiant Servers Troubleshooting Guide"](http://www.hp.com/support/ProLiant_TSG_en) (page 23, to be precise).

In the [Smart Array User's Guide](http://bizsupport1.austin.hp.com/bc/docs/support/SupportManual/c01608507/c01608507.pdf), the "Drive Procedures" section starting on page 74 will be helpful.

HP's Array Diagnostic Utility (ADU) may also be useful here.  It used to be downloaded as a separate utility, but recent releases of ACU have the ADU functionality built in.

In general, ewwhite is correct.  If you pull the failed drive and replace it with a new one, the Smart Array will detect the replacement and start rebuilding the volume (you can use ACU to verify that the volume is rebuilding).  I would modify his suggestion a bit, though, and say that this *must* be done while the system is running.  Replacing a failed drive while the system is powered off can cause problems in some cases.